# How does below code only changes completed value of third member of the array?

Tags: javascript

How does below code only changes completed value of third member of the array?

```js
[{id: 0, completed: true},
  {id: 1, completed: false},
  {id: 2, completed: false}
].map((todo) => {
  if (todo.id !== 2) {
    return todo;
  }
  return {...todo, completed: !todo.completed};
})
```

Comment: Because the 1st and 2nd members of the array don't have id of 2.

Comment: thanks for you answer ,but i need to know how the code works step by step

Comment: Yes I know.

Result of 
if (todo.id !== 2) {
    return todo;
  }

Is  [
    undefined,
    { id: 1,  completed: false},
    { id: 2,  completed: false}
  ]

But how return {...todo, completed: !todo.completed} works

Comment: `...todo` is spread syntax. `{...todo, completed: !todo.completed}` is the same as `{id: 2, completed: false, completed: !todo.completed}`, which becomes `{id: 2, completed: true}`. See [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Answer (score 0):

If the `todo.id !== 2` the function returns (and stops its execution) before make further changes, and just the third element has `todo.id == 2`

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to Javascript and programming for such.
Please find the added comments to your code.

---

```
[{id: 0, completed: true},
  {id: 1, completed: false},
  {id: 2, completed: false}
]
.map((todo) => {      
  if (todo.id !== 2){   // Execute only when the id is not 2            
    return todo;   
  }

  // Thus when the id is 2
  // this return statement will work 
  // return the item with the opposite of "completed" property
  // and ofcourse you want the item added back to todo, hence ...todo with the following 
  // expression.

  return {...todo, completed: !todo.completed}; 
})

=============================================
To better understand the spread operator, consider the following example:
------------------------------------
let numberStore = [0, 1, 2];
let newNumber = 12;
numberStore = [...numberStore, newNumber];
numberStore = [...numberStore, newNumber];
numberStore = [...numberStore, newNumber];

Result:
console.log(numberStore) ==> [0, 1, 2, 12, 12, 12]
```